# Knockoutjs Div altera atualizar tag <a>

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Tenho essa Div com knockoutjs qunado ela altera eu tenho que troca minhas tag  para hide ou visible

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px; width:150px; float:left;">${Name()}</div>

<a data-bind="visible:CheckedPlus" onclick="attach(event, this, '${TypeID()}')" title="Associar" style="width:16px;  margin-top:5px; height:16px; float:right;">
                        @Html.Image("fugue", "plus-circle-blue.png")
                    </a>
                <a data-bind="visible:CheckedEdit" onclick="attach(event, this, '${TypeID()}')" title="Deletar" style="width:16px;  margin-top:5px; height:16px; float:right;">
                    @Html.Image("fugue", "cross-circle.png")
                </a>
```

Porém quando a informação vem do banco a tag  se altera, pois knockoutjs é executado.